# what are all arguments KubeletExtraArgs supports in GO NodeRegistrationOptions object?

Tags: kubeadm

I am using kubeadm for installation of kubernetes using config files.

Below is the type of "NodeRegistrationOptions" struct in go language. I would like to know what are all arugments "KubeletExtraArgs" supports?

I found few options like node-labels and register-with-taints. But i want to know from documentation, what are all arguments it supports?

Please share if you have any link for this.

```
From go docuementation,
type NodeRegistrationOptions struct {

    // Name is the `.Metadata.Name` field of the Node API object that will be created in this `kubeadm init` or `kubeadm join` operation.
    // This field is also used in the CommonName field of the kubelet's client certificate to the API server.
    // Defaults to the hostname of the node if not provided.
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`

    // CRISocket is used to retrieve container runtime info. This information will be annotated to the Node API object, for later re-use
    CRISocket string `json:"criSocket,omitempty"`

    // Taints specifies the taints the Node API object should be registered with. If this field is unset, i.e. nil, in the `kubeadm init` process
    // it will be defaulted to []v1.Taint{'node-role.kubernetes.io/master=""'}. If you don't want to taint your control-plane node, set this field to an
    // empty slice, i.e. `taints: []` in the YAML file. This field is solely used for Node registration.
    Taints []v1.Taint `json:"taints,omitempty"`

    // KubeletExtraArgs passes through extra arguments to the kubelet. The arguments here are passed to the kubelet command line via the environment file
    // kubeadm writes at runtime for the kubelet to source. This overrides the generic base-level configuration in the kubelet-config-1.X ConfigMap
    // Flags have higher priority when parsing. These values are local and specific to the node kubeadm is executing on.
    KubeletExtraArgs map[string]string `json:"kubeletExtraArgs,omitempty"`
}
```

https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta1

Comment: These are any argument and parameter supported by kubelet as documented here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/